# Change the values of some elements according to the index using thrust

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, gpu, thrust

- **Problem description**:
  I want to use *thrust* to set the value of some elements in an array based on another **index** array. One simple example is shown below:

```
// input:
int array[10] = {1,9,9,6,0,1,1,6,1,4};
int set_num = -1;
int index[4] = {0,2,4,6};
// output:
array[10] = {-1,9,-1,6,-1,1,-1,6,1,4};
```

- **My idea**:
  I don't know how to accomplish it using *thrust*, so I write my own kernel. The code snippet is demonstrated below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"


#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

// kernel function
template <typename T>
__global__ void setNumInArray(T *arrays, int *index, T set_num, int num_index)
{
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (tid > num_index)
        return;
    arrays[index[tid]] = set_num;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int vec_length = 4069;                             // length of the array
    thrust::device_vector<int>vec(vec_length);
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);      // the values are generated by thrust::sequence
    const int num_index = 16;                                         // length of the index array
    thrust::device_vector<int>index(num_index);                       // the index array is generated by thrust::sequence
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, index.begin(), index.end(), 64,10);

    // type convert: thrust->normal device pointer
    int *d_vec = reinterpret_cast<int*>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vec.data()));
    int *d_index = reinterpret_cast<int*>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(index.data()));

    int set_num = 0;    // the value I want to set

    int block_size = 64;
    setNumInArray<int> <<<1, block_size >>> (d_vec, d_index, set_num, num_index);

    thrust::host_vector<int>h_vec(vec_length);                         // check the result
    h_vec = vec;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < vec_length; ii++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n",ii+1,h_vec[ii]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program can output the right answer. However, I want to avoid the type convert between thrust variables and common device variables (I use lots of thrust functions in the other part of my project), and also avoid adjusting the block/grid size to achieve better performance. So how can I achieve it with *thrust*?

- **Working environment**:

  - OS: Windows10
  - GPU:RTX2060
  - CUDA:10.2
  - IDE: VS2015
- **Additional questions**:

  1. Is my type convert method in the code snippet right? Will it cause some potential problems?
  2. Why the complier (VS2015) can not find the *cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSizes* ? I want to use it to determine the most optimal block size.

Comment: The use of `reinterpret_cast` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

You can use thrust::for_each with a lambda function. But I have not benchmarked this and maybe your kernel is faster.

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int vec_length = 4069;                        
    thrust::device_vector<int>vec(vec_length);
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);     
    const int num_index = 16;                                         
    thrust::device_vector<int>index(num_index);                       
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, index.begin(), index.end(), 64,10);
    int *d_vec = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vec.data());
    int set_num = 0;

    auto changeValue = [=] __device__(int y) { d_vec[y] = set_num; };
    thrust::for_each(thrust::device, index.begin(), index.end(), changeValue);

    thrust::host_vector<int>h_vec(vec_length);
    h_vec = vec;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < vec_length; ii++) {
        if(h_vec[ii] == set_num)
            printf("%d: %d\n",ii+1,h_vec[ii]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using "permutation_iterator" and "fill", I slightly edited eritjo's code.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>

int main()
{
    const unsigned int vec_length = 4069;                        
    thrust::device_vector<int>vec(vec_length);
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);     
    const int num_index = 16;                                         
    thrust::device_vector<int>index(num_index);                       
    thrust::sequence(thrust::device, index.begin(), index.end(), 64,10);
    int set_num = 0;

    typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator Iter;
    thrust::permutation_iterator<Iter, Iter> iter(vec.begin(), index.begin());
    thrust::fill(iter, iter+num_index, set_num);

    thrust::host_vector<int>h_vec(vec_length);
    h_vec = vec;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < vec_length; ii++) {
        if(h_vec[ii] == set_num)
            printf("%d: %d\n",ii+1,h_vec[ii]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```